# Using local storage to keep name and picture on screen after refresh (F5)

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a simple drop down with names and pictures associated with those names. I would like to use local storage to keep the selected name and photo on the screen after a refresh of the page. Not sure of the best way to target these variables so that local storage can help me save the selected "driver" for the day.

Here is my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var linkData = [
            ['Images/mark.jpg'],
            ['Images/chad.jpg'],
            ['Images/jeff.jpg']
        ]
        //preload the pics
        var picO = new Array();
        for(i=0; i < linkData.length; i++){
            picO[i] = new Image();
            picO[i].src = linkData[i][0];
        }
        function show(val) {
            document.getElementById('picture').src = picO[val-1].src;
            document.getElementById('caption').href = linkData[val-1][1];
        }
        window.onload=function(){
            show(1);
        }
    </script>

    <div>
        <select id="driver" onchange="show(this.value);">
            <option value="1">Mark</option>
            <option value="2">Chad</option>
            <option value="3">Jeff</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <a id="caption" href="#"><img id="picture" src="" /></a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Confirm Driver" onclick="save()"/>
    </div>
    <script>
        function save() {
          var todaysDriver = document.getElementById('driver').value;
          localStorage.setItem('driver',todaysDriver);
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the way you can proceed. You just need to modify your onload event.

```
window.onload=function(){
        var selectedDriver = localStorage.getItem('driver');
        if(selectedDriver === null){
            selectedDriver = 1 ;
        }
        document.getElementById('driver').selectedIndex = selectedDriver - 1;
        show(selectedDriver);
}
```

Also if it has to be saved just for the day, you need to store the dateSaved as well in localStorage and compared the current date with this before displaying.

Also you may wish to download the picture on drop down change instead of pre-fetching

Comment: That works for keeping the picture that I select on the screen after refresh, but the name associated with the picture is defaulting back to "Mark". Is there suppose to be another .onload function for that separately or can it be part of the one you provided?